# Generate Unique Keys From Data using UPDATE SET FROM pattern

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a database staging table that is used to store data fed in from another system before I use it to populate several database tables.

I was relying on the "primary keys" in the data getting fed in being unique, however it turns out that they are not unique at all e.g. the key "1" can apply to "Value A" and "VALUE B" thus it is obviously not a primary key!!!

***As I no longer trust the data I was thinking of generating my own keys based on the contents of the staging table. E.g. for "Column A" I want to generate a unique integer based key based on the distinct values in that column. Is this possible via an UPDATE SET FROM or another mechanism?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to generate a unique integer based key based on the distinct
> values in that column

You can use `dense_rank()` and a CTE to number the rows.

```
;with C as
(
  select ID,
         dense_rank() over(order by ColumnA) as rn
  from YourTable
)
update C
set ID = rn
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/122782/

Comment: DENSE_RANK() does not provide a unique set of distinct values, but gives two rows with the same distinct value the same rank.

Comment: @ChrisGessler - You are correct and that is what OP wants. He wants the same ID for values that are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, why not generate a unique key based on row number or roll your own identity-esque column?

Comment: I have no control over the query that I use to populate the staging table so was thinking it would something that would be carried out after the population of the table which will have duplicate values.

Comment: A column set as an Identity may still be a valid way of approaching this. A trigger would probably have some performance considerations, depending on how often things are inserted, and how.